# Speed up TeX-insert-macro on \input

Tags: latex, auctex

In `latex-mode` when I use `TeX-insert-macro` to type a `\input{...}`
macro, Auctex conveniently offers filename completion, which is great.
However, it seems to search a lot of places to compile the completion
list, because emacs hangs for almost a minute on my poor little
laptop.

**Is there a way for `TeX-insert-macro` to offer dumb filename completion?**
By "dumb", I mean the one you get when calling `find-file`. Most of
the time the file I want to input is just one directory away, so that
would be more than fine.

If that's not possible, **is there another way to speed it up?**
I noticed when I insert the `\include` macro the list of filenames is
much shorter, so maybe there's a way to use that list for the `\input`
macro as well.

Comment: There is also `cdlatex-insert-filename` which comes with cdlatex package. I find it helpful for inserting graphic files into figure environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few solutions:

First, there is a variable customizing this behavior: `TeX-arg-input-file-search`.

> If `TeX-arg-input-file` should search for files.
>   If the value is t, files in TeX's search path are searched for
>   and provided for completion.  The file name is then inserted
>   without directory and extension.  If the value is nil, the file
>   name can be specified manually and is inserted with a path
>   relative to the directory of the current buffer's file and with
>   extension.  If the value is `ask`, you are asked for the method
>   to use every time `TeX-arg-input-file` is called.

This piece of documentation is, imho, quite not clear enough, but setting it to `nil` seems to do the job.

```
(setq TeX-arg-input-file-search nil)
```

This variable affects all functions that call `TeX-arg-input-file`, including `input`, `include` and `usepackage`. For the latter, this behavior may be unexpected.

Then there is a more hacky solution which should work for all functions: `TeX-arg-input-file` features a `local` flag for this behavior (this flag is for example set to `t` for `include`).

Apparently, you can override any other setting by just adding another entry for the command, so:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 
  (lambda nil 
     (TeX-add-symbols '("input" (TeX-arg-input-file "File" t)))))
```

A last solution, if you have long-lasting emacs sessions, is to simply let it go. It seems that the "searching files" phase caches its results, so it should be called only once per session.

Comment: Awesome! I was expecting a bit of a hack, guess I underestimated auctex.

Comment: Hmpf, it seems that hack was indeed the way to go, see my edit. If the hacky solution suits your needs better, please tell me so that I can rearrange the answer.

Comment: You're right, for usepackage that would be undesirable. Thanks for the update. It does indeed cache the results, but a delay of ~1min is enough to bother me even if it is only once per buffer.

Comment: I rearranged the content. Looking at the code again, I was wrong, `TeX-global-input-files` (the variable containing the result of the search) is not buffer-local, so the search should happen only once per emacs *session*. Maybe this would be more interesting if it could happen asyncronously, though, a freeze of ~1min is indeed too long.